# Upgrade Sitecore XP 8.1 to 9,1

Tags: upgrade

Experts

We are using Sitecore 8.1 Upd 3. However, as this version has been discontinued at the end of 2018,
I started considering upgrading to the latest Sitecore 9.1.

Referring to Sitecore's compatibility table, in 8.1 and 9.1, in all of OS / SQL / Mongo / Solr,
I found that a different version is required.

In addition, the site we operate is on the virtual server on IaaS, and it is not easy for users to upgrade the OS,
I can not assume it.

Our environment is follows

```
Sitecore 8.1 Update 3
OS Windows Server 2012 R2
SQL SQL Server 2012
Mongo 3.0
Solr 4.1
```

A question

Is it possible to upgrade Sitecore from 8.1 to 9.1 without upgrading the OS (Windows)?

Is it possible to run Sitecore 8.1 with OS / SQL / Mongo / Solr version adapted to the requirements of 9.1?

I hope you will receive wisdom.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because multiple questions, too broad, non-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about running Sitecore 9.1 on Windows Server 2012 R2 (I suspect you can't), but it is certainly possible to run Sitecore 8.1 with the requirements for Sitecore 9.1. So you could set up a new environment with the requirements for SC91 and run the SC81 site on it before upgrading.